# How can you make an IOS Screesaver like app that launches automatically and comes back after idle?

Tags: iphone-privateapi, autostart, screensaver

I saw this working in a phone shop. Its like a perfect screensaver app with information. How can this work on a non jailbroken phone?

https://youtu.be/HN9L1yBJr98

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Why do we think the display phone is not jail broken?

Comment: That is a good question, tomorrow I will check it. We were informed by the shop owner mobile operator that the phones are not jailbroken. Is there a way to determine easyly (apart from looking for cydia)?

Comment: I have no idea! But I can't imagine how this could be done for a non jailbroken phone, so I have to question the premise of the question. :)